# Delete button not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

Here's my Delete button:

```
<td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="delete(<?php echo $data->emp_id;?>);">
        <button id="button_delete">Delete</button>
    </a>
</td>
```

Here's my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
    function delete(id)
    {
        var r=confirm("Do you want to delete this employee?");
        if (r==true)
        {
            window.location = url+"index.php/admin_logins/employee4/"+id;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's my controller (`admin_logins.php`) method -

```
function employee4($emp_id)
{
    $this->employee_model->delete_employee($emp_id);
    $this->index();
}
```

And here's my model(`employee_model.php`) method -

```
public function delete_employee($emp_id)
{
    $this->db->where('employee.emp_id',$emp_id);
    return $this->db->delete('employee');
}
```

My table name is `employee` and my database is MySQL.

```
Column Name         Datatype
   id                 int
  emp_id             varchar(15)
  emp_name           varchar(50)
  emp_mobile_no      varchar(15)
```

Whenever I click the **Delete** button, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure delete function included in the right place? I mean if it's really accessible for the page you execute, anyway u can check console for any errors

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ for coding. How can I check console? Any idea?

Comment: when you execute the page in browser, u said button click not works, so try developer tools to see any javascript errors

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J in the web browser

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J. It doesn't tell me anything about this delete function in my Javascript.

Comment: have you checked your php error log?

Comment: @Lokesh Jain return what?

Comment: onclick="return delete(<?php echo $data->emp_id;?>);

Comment: Checked console. Got this - `ReferenceError: DS00467 is not defined` 'DS00467' is the emp_id I want to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the function name `delete` I tested it and gave me this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete

So try to name it with another name, ex: `deleteEntry` or `deleteEmployee`

`delete` is the javascript command so it's reserved word, and please always avoid to name functions or variables with reserved words

Alternatively I suggest to use the solution:

```
<td>
    <a href="index.php/admin_logins/employee4/<?php echo $data->emp_id;?>" 
       onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this employee?');">
        <button id="button_delete">Delete</button>
    </a>
</td>
```

Give `a` tags href, and onclick just return confirmation message

Comment: Ok, I changed the function name to deleteEmployee but still nothing happens.

Comment: you have to change it for function and also for calliung it

Comment: Changed both. Still no luck.

Comment: Did you check for error? also I added simpler solution

Comment: Ok, thanks, my javascript onclick function is working now, I'm getting the confirm message, but after I click 'yes', I get 
404 Page Not Found error.

Comment: Thats another problem, maybe you need one slash `/` between `index.php...` and `url` variable?

Answer (score 3):

No need to pass `$emp_id`. Your controller function should be look like below :

```
function employee4()
{
    $emp_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->employee_model->delete_employee($emp_id);
    $this->index();
}
```

In your case uri segment value is `3`

Comment: Thanks again @hardik. But now I'm getting 404 page not found error.

Comment: Did you check in your db row is deleted or not??

Comment: Because of it seem may be redirection page issue.

Comment: I checked in my db. Data is not deleted.

Comment: Did you check url in your browser??

Comment: Yes. http://localhost/CI/index.php/admin_logins/index.php/admin_logins/employee4/DS00467

Comment: I can see the problem with your browser url. Your url should be http://localhost/CI/index.php/admin_logins/employee4/DS00467. Try to run this url manually and see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Faced same problem with delete button and Finally I figured out these codes and it's working exactly the way I want.

// ***** My Controller name : Main *****

```
public function delete_user()
{
    $this->model_users->deleteM($id);
 // whatever you like here.. redirect('') OR load view;
  }

// ***** Model *****

  public function deleteM($data)
  {
     $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
     $this->db->delete('employee');
  }

// ***** VIEW ******* 

<?php $bttn = '<button name="delete" onclick="ConfirmDelete()"></button>'; 
echo anchor("main/delete_user/$row->id", $bttn);?>
```

> If you need help on this VIEW you can ask anytime, for now I assume everything's cool !

```
// ***** OnClick JS Function ******

<script>
  function ConfirmDelete()
  {
    var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (x)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#id_for_your_delete_button').on('click', function(){
     var id = $('#entry_id').val();
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?= site_url("your_controller_here"); ?>',
          data: id
    });
});
```

Comment: but this is not the actual problem, it's in JS

Comment: Here you use SQL directly instead of Active records. Why do you think this this should solve the problem?

Comment: Nope. Nothing happens.

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same thing other than using ajax?